# Has Trump Pence Administration attempted to block rules restricting leaks of methane?

Tags: united-states

[Refusefascism.org](https://refusefascism.org/what-the-trumppence-regime-has-done-and-says-they-will-do/#white-supremacy) says:

> [Trump Pence Administration has] Attempted to block rules restricting leaks of methane, an even more harmful greenhouse gas than CO2, from landfills and from oil and gas wells.

Is that true?

Comment: It seems they're more concerned with blocking other sorts of leaks :-)

Comment: Methane emissions have been restricted since the 50's. Certainly the rules, limits,etc have been made restrictive more many times since then. " During drilling operations"  , methane is normally zero or very low, but like anything else there are occasionally exceptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Washington Post's article, [Trump administration delays rules limiting methane emissions](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/trump-administration-delays-rules-limiting-methane-emissions/2017/06/14/0e7d50fa-512b-11e7-be25-3a519335381c_story.html?utm_term=.1ccb0cd398de), says:

> The Trump administration has delayed for two years a pair of rules that would have limited the release of methane, a potent greenhouse gas, from oil and gas operations across the country. The Environmental Protection Agency announced on Tuesday it would postpone a 2016 rule limiting methane and smog-forming pollutants from oil and gas wells. The decision was made at the request of firms that would be affected by rule as the EPA reconsidered whether to implement the stricter standard. Separately, the Bureau of Land Management entered a notice into the Federal Register on Friday stating it would delay compliance with a rule finalized in November that would limit methane burned off from drilling operations on federal and tribal lands.

But it was deemed illegal.

Fox News, [Federal judges order EPA to implement Obama-era methane regulation](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2017/07/03/federal-judges-order-epa-to-implement-obama-era-methane-regulation.html):

> A federal appeals court in Washington ruled Monday that the head of the Environmental Protection Agency overstepped his authority in trying to delay implementation of a new rule requiring oil and gas companies to monitor and reduce methane leaks. In a split decision, the three-judge panel from the U.S. Court of Appeals for the District of Columbia Circuit ordered the EPA to move forward with the Obama-era requirement that aims to reduce planet-warming emissions from oil and gas operations.

Comment: These are the references and context Craig's answer was missing. Nicely done.

Comment: I hope you don't mind: I edited, to put the titles/headlines of the referenced newspaper articles in the hyperlinks. I think the titles informative (so a good summary to include in the answer), and it's a good habit because they could be helpful in the finding the article again if the URLs of the referenced web site are changed in future.